# How Do I Batch Convert to Ogg Theora with FFmpeg6?

Tags: ffmpeg, mac

Good evening.
I'm struggling to figure out a set of ffmpeg6 commands/flags for the following scenario:
I have a large batch of 1080p 5.1ch lossless MKV's (courtesy of MakeMKV) that I want to encode to Ogg Theora specifically, downscale to 720p, 2ch audio, and both video and audio at a somewhat higher Q (quality) setting for both. Can anyone offer some direction? I am stuck on MacOS on a 2020 Intel Macbook Air, and no Linux or BSD distro can use the built in keyboard and trackpad so far as I can tell (believe me, I have tried many.) GUI tools like nch prism and miro produce poor quality, laggy video while ffmpeg6 does well, but I'd really like to encode more than one at a time. Thank you.